# Calling RESTful webservices in Appcelerator Titanium Studio

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm very new to Appcelerator titanium studio. Could you please help me out how to call webservice (Java Based) in Appcelerator titanium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Titanium.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) to make RESTful calls.

**Example for GET requests**

```
var url = "http://www.appcelerator.com";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    // function called when the response data is available
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
});
// Prepare the connection.
client.open("GET", url);
// Send the request.
client.send();
```

**Example for POST requests**

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    //handle response, which at minimum will be an HTTP status code
};
xhr.open('POST','http://www.myblog.com/post.php');
xhr.send({
    title:'My awesome blog',
    body:'Today I met Susy at the laundromat.  Best day EVAR\!'
});
```

It supports the verbs GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH

Comment: Thanks .@Arturo León.